# Use ffmpeg to trim off X seconds of a y4m video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-editing

I'm trying to trim the first second off some .y4m videos.

Using the answer provided [here](https://superuser.com/a/269960/474158), I am able to trim the first second off a .mp4 video and then play back the output video:

```
ffmpeg -ss 1 -i input.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy output.mp4
```

When I try to use the same command with a .y4m video, however, I get the following error and the file that is output is blank:

```
ffmpeg -ss 1 -i input.y4m -vcodec copy -acodec copy output.y4m
```

> yuv4mpegpipe @ 0x5628e3af63c0] ERROR: Codec not supported.
>   Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid data found when processing input

Why is this command not working with a .y4m file? Do I need to add additional parameters? Is there another way to trim the first second off a .y4m video?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to a change in the Y4M muxer, you'll need to re-encode, but this is a lossless op.

```
ffmpeg -ss 1 -i input.y4m output.y4m
```

Y4Ms can't have any audio, so audio codec option removed.